# woocommerce applying cart coupons

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am currently developing a plugin for woocommerce, and have the following code which adds a discount code if the total of the cart is in between the 2 values:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'woobd_add_discount_if_enabled');

function woobd_add_discount_if_enabled()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 10
        && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total <= 100
    ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount('layer1_discount');
    } else {        
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons('layer1_discount');
        $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
    }
}
```

The above works fine, however i would like to add another if statement like this which adds another 2 values:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'woobd_add_discount_if_enabled');

function woobd_add_discount_if_enabled()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 10
        && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total <= 100
    ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount('layer1_discount');
    } else {        
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons('layer1_discount');
        $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
    }

    if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 100
        && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total <= 200
    ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount('layer2_discount');
    } else {        
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons('layer2_discount');
        $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
    }
}
```

For some reason the second if statement only get detected, completely ignoring the first one. Is there anything noticeably wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you change the two separate statements into an if, elseif, else - it'll work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'woobd_add_discount_if_enabled');

function woobd_add_discount_if_enabled()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 10
        && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total <= 100
    ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount('layer1_discount');
    } elseif ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 100
        && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total <= 200
    ) {        
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount('layer2_discount');
    } else {        
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons('layer1_discount');
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons('layer2_discount');
        $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
    }


}
```